# How to access all JFrames in different threads of the same application

Tags: java, swing, reflection, jframe

How to access different `JFrame`  executing in different event dispatch threads of a Java application Please go through the SSCCE posed here 
[Will new instance of JVM or reflection help in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573259/will-new-instance-of-jvm-or-reflection-help-in-this-case)

In the end as I mentioned If the following code is added to the first class

```
Frame[] f2 = JFrame.getFrames();

for(Frame fx: f2){
    System.out.println(fx.getTitle());
    fx.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
}
```

only a single frame is returned if added to second class in sequence in SSCCE two frames are returned and if added to third class All frames are returned. Is this a problem due to event dispatch threads what is the reason behind this behavior. How to access all frames from Main frame i.e., MyApp.

Why does JFrame.getFrames(); returns awt Frames say for example if I want to change the default close operation of all JFrames in my application  gerFrames returns awt frames which if caset in JFrame produces an exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   [Ljava.awt.Frame; cannot be cast to [Ljavax.swing.JFrame; at
>   myApp.MYApp.main(MYApp.java:48)

Comment: `[Ljava.awt.Frame; cannot be cast to [Ljavax.swing.JFrame; at myApp.MYApp.main(MYApp.java:48)` this is because you are trying to cast the _array_. You need to cast the frames _individually_ as mKorbel describes.

Comment: Didn't I just answer this @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573259/will-new-instance-of-jvm-or-reflection-help-in-this-case/11573328#comment15312477_11573328 ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry I had already posted this here and it was not answered so I though to ask in in continuation there the last part :(

Comment: @sand1988, no worries, bust thought I was going crazy ;)

Comment: 1) Anything that requires more than one source code is not an SSCCE. 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

code line

```
Window[] allWindows = Window.getWindows();
```

returns arrays of all `Top-Level Containers` from current `JVM`

- `J/Frame`
- `J/Dialog(JOptionPane)`
- `J/Window`

have to test if

```
if (allWindows[i] instanceof JFrame) {
```